# Ubuntu 21.04 (5.11.0-25-generic), Thinkpad T14S (AMD) - USB ports not reacting / working anymore

Tags: usb, thinkpad

maybe someone has come across the same problem or can help me otherwise.

Since two days, my two USB ports are not reacting anymore. Nothing is recognized or charged on them (SSD drive, charging my phone & watch, USB splitter, mouse, keyboard...). With and without power connection of the Laptop.

I run Ubuntu 21.04 (kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic).

I have a Thinkpad T14S, AMD version.
-> https://www.campuspoint.de/20ujs00k00-lenovocampus-thinkpad-t14s-amd.html

I deactivated and activated them in the BIOS it doesn't solve the problem.

Unfortunately, I do not understand where the problem could be.

About tips and ideas I would be very very grateful.

Many thanks already.

Christopher

Comment: Sorry, you are right, Ubuntu 21.04. I updated a bit frustrated with the hope to sneak away from this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the USB ports haven't been short-circuited (ie. a thumb-drive wasn't pulled out straight & two 5V wires connected?   fully-ejecting with power-off of thumb-drives should prevent this, but if it wasn't done, the USB ports maybe dead).  By testing with a *live* system (I'd use a different OS) you can test they work & thus spend time looking for a software solution like this question; but I'd check our your hardware first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AMD System fresh install , Only USB 3 working (IOMMU?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841390/amd-system-fresh-install-only-usb-3-working-iommu)

Answer (score 1):

ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-1 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu two of the three USB ports not working, maybe after kernel upgrade. Disabled "USB Always On" on Bios settings to get them working again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me by changing the grub file.

[AMD System fresh install , Only USB 3 working (IOMMU?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841390/amd-system-fresh-install-only-usb-3-working-iommu)

If you have similar problems, don't hesitate to contact me, I spend way too much time with this...

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "USB Always On" in Bios was probably the trick which makes USB working again under Ubuntu 18.04 on a ThinkPad notebook.