# /dev/ttyUSB0 not created for one specific usb device

Tags: 20.04, usb

I'm trying to control a robot arm that connects to my computer over serial through USB. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Zephyrus G15 (AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS). This method of communication works fine on other peoples' computers.

I have tried with multiple USB cables, multiple USB ports, and multiple robotic arms, all to no avail. My computer is able to communicate fine with other microcontrollers, and they create /dev/ttyACM0. This leads me to believe it's not a (external) hardware problem.

When I connect the arm and run `dmesg`, it shows "Could not enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?" and "attempt power cycle" on either usb1-port1 or usb1-port2 depending on which port I plug the cable into. `lsusb` shows no changes with the cable plugged in or unplugged. Both of these commands output as expected with any other USB device.

I've uninstalled brltty as suggested by a few other posts. I've run `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt update`. I've rebooted my computer after each attempt to fix it.

Any ideas about what could be causing this with only this specific microcontroller?

Edit: The arm is not recognized as a USB device in my windows installation, either. I'm plugging directly into the root usb hub, and I've tried both that exist on my computer.

Update: I've solved it. For some reason, it only works when plugged into my USB-C ports, through a USB-C to USB-A converter. These ports are on a different root hub than the USB-A ports. I don't know why this is the case. If anyone has a theory I would love to hear it.

Comment: @user535733 In the list of multiple things that I've tried is more robotic arms. Unfortunately none of them work. This arm does work with other computers.

Comment: Are you saying that 1) Arm A works properly works properly when connected to other systems, and that 2) Other arms work properly when connected to your system, but that 3) Only Arm A fails to connect to only your system?

Comment: @user535733 Sorry for the confusion. Arm A and B both work with other systems, and neither work with my system

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/843477/1004020 solve the problem?

Comment: No luck. My BIOS doesn't seem to have an IOMMU option, just SVM. I tried messing around with /etc/default/grub with various options for iommu and amd_iommu and didn't come up with anything (besides kernel panic with iommu=off).